# set a default value on select dropdown using using angular formly

Tags: angular, angular-formly, ngx-formly

**Hi , how do we set a default value for a select field using angular formly library**

```
    this.uiFormFactory.createSelect(
          Location,
          this.store.select(StoreUtil.getParameterOptions(ParameterId.Location)),
          PersonDetailsFieldLabel.location,
          {
            required: true,
            select: { searchable: true, virtualScroll: true, defaultValue: 'Home' },
            readonly: false,
          }
        ),
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use something like this:

```js
  form = new FormGroup({});
  options: FormlyFormOptions = {};
  fields: FormlyFieldConfig[] = [
    {
      key: 'select box',
      type: 'select',
      defaultValue: 'value1',
      templateOptions: {
        label: 'select something',
        options: [
          { label: 'value 1', value: 'value1' },
          { label: 'value 2', value: 'value2' },
          { label: 'value 3', value: 'value3' },
        ],
      },
    },
  ];

  submit() {
    console.log('submit form');
  }
}
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
  <formly-form [fields]="fields" [options]="options" [form]="form"></formly-form>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit-button" [disabled]="!form.valid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

of course, you can set the options array as you wish